# What makes cola efficient as a rust remover?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I actually tested submerging a bunch of old rusty knives blades in a cup of plain cola for a few days not expecting much. To my amazement the myth held true, coke is a really good rust remover.

So what is the chemistry behind it?

Comment: This may have been asked before.

Comment: I searched but found nothing

Comment: You're right. It wasn't asked before, but it was discussed in another question. Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/chemically-removing-rust-without-leaving-any-unwanted-residues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust consists of insoluble [iron oxides and hydroxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust), $\ce {Fe2O3·nH2O}$ and $\ce{FeO(OH)·Fe(OH)3}$. Acidifying these compounds protonates the oxide and hydroxide anions to for water:

$$\ce{O^{2-} + 2H^+ \rightarrow H_2O}$$
$$\ce{OH^{-} + H^+ \rightarrow H_2O}$$

This leaves the soluble iron $\ce{Fe(III)}$, which can be washed away.

Many colas contain phosphoric acid, and are quite acidic (Coke has a pH of ~2.5 according to [this science fair project](http://www.selah.k12.wa.us/soar/sciproj2005/Graphs/MarshalN.pdf)), thus they can dissolve the oxides.

Comment: It's not that Fe(III) gets washed away necessarily but that Fe(III) phosphates gets formed which works afterwards as a protection layer like the oxides for e.g. aluminium.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't think about the phosphate ion. Good point.

Comment: It's not just a point but [what happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid#Rust_removal) :)